# How should we use async await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I was looking at how to use async await, but I do not quite get it when we have multiple methods invoking each other. Should we always use await or should we only use await when we are actually ready to use the result?

So for example should we do it like this:

```
async Task<string[]> FooAsync()
{
    var info = await Func1();
    return info.split('.');
}

async Task<string> Func1()
{
    return await Func2();
}

async Task<string> Func2()
{
    return await tcpClient.ReadStringAsync();
}
```

Or like this:

```
async Task<string[]> FooAsync()
{
    var info = await Func1();
    return info.split('.');
}

Task<string> Func1()
{
    return Func2();
}

Task<string> Func2()
{
    return tcpClient.ReadStringAsync();
}
```

Per example 1, should we always use await in every method? 
***Or***
Per example 2 should we only use await on the top-most method when we start using the result?

Comment: Every-time you call `await` it creates a lump of code and goes through a statemachine, by *returning* a *task* you are sometimes creating a small efficiency. However, there are situations that you might want to poke any exceptions on the returned task (that will be *awaited*). i think from here you want to start looking at Stephen Cleary and Stephen Toubs awesome blogs on the Async and Await Pattern

Comment: `It Depends`. If you *don't* want to do anything with the result, you don't need to use `await` and can just return the value. Debugging becomes a bit harder though, as you can't check the return value in `Func2` itself during debugging, nor can you handle exceptions locally.

Comment: I can recommend the [AsyncGuidance](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#prefer-asyncawait-over-directly-returning-task) from David Fowler. In this case: `Prefer async/await over directly returning Task`

Comment: Additionaly when you await a task you are not guaranteed to be on the same thread anymore but one could say that is of no interesst. Furthermore awaiting a task in the wrong place could led to deadlocks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Every-time you call `await` it creates a lump of code to bundle up *variables*, captures the *synchronization* context (if applicable) and create a continuation into an `IAsyncStateMachine`.

Essentially, returning a `Task` without the `async` *keyword* will give you a small *run-time* efficiency and save you a bunch of *CIL*. Do note that the *Async* feature in *.NET* also has many optimizations already. Also note (and importantly) that returning a `Task` in a `using` statement will likely throw an *Already Disposed Exception*.

You can compare the *CIL* and plumbing differences here

- [Forwarded Task](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACg5dgxBWNdKAZgQCY4BhOAbwyy3u1KgDY4ARAewGUuBbAKYAXABYBLAHYBzABQBKJrSUMoAdgSsAdB0EAbAIYBPWYhgx5hBgF8lKktgAscALIGpCupgYMVP7nxCYlJy8loA6u7CClY2GNZAA===)
- [Async Method](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACg5dgxBWNdKAZgQCY4BhOAbwyy3u1KgA4EA2OAEQHsBlXgFsApgBcAFgEsAdgHMAFAEomtVQygBOTgDpuIgDYBDAJ4LEMGEsIMAvqvUlsAFjgBZI7OV1MDBur8+QVFJWUUlHQB1TzFlGzsMWyA=)

So if your method is just forwarding a `Task` and not wanting anything from it, you could easily just drop the `async` keyword and return the `Task` directly.

More-so, there are times when we do more than just *forwarding* and there is branching involved. This is where, [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.8) come into play to help deal with the logic of what may arise in a method. I.e If you want to give a *result* (there and then), or *return* a `Task` that is *completed* (respectively).

Lastly, the *Async and Await Pattern* has subtle differences when dealing with *Exceptions*. If you are returning a `Task`, you can use [`Task.FromException<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception?view=netframework-4.8) to pop any exception on the the returned `Task` like an `async` method would normally do.

**Nonsensical example**

```
public Task<int> DoSomethingAsync(int someValue)
{
   try
   {
      if (someValue == 1)
         return Task.FromResult(3); // Return a completed task

      return MyAsyncMethod(); // Return a task
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return Task.FromException<int>(e); // Place exception on the task
   }
}
```

In short, if you don't quite understand what is going on, just `await` it; the overhead will be minimal. However, if you understand the subtitles of how to return a *task result*, a *completed task*, placing an *exception on a task*, or just *forwarding*. You can save your self some *CIL* and give your code a small performance gain by dropping the `async` keyword returning a task directly and bypassing the `IAsyncStateMachine`.

---

At about this time, I would look up the Stack Overflow user and author *Stephen Cleary*, and Mr. Parallel *Stephen Toub*. They have a plethora of blogs and books dedicated solely to the *Async and Await Pattern*, all the pitfalls, coding etiquette and lots more information you will surely find interesting.

Comment: Relevant link to Stephen Cleary's blog, also reported in Fabio's answer: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Comment: await will ensure the method resumes on the same UI context, not the same thread?

Comment: @variable yes indeed the same sync / execution context and same thread.

Answer (score 14):

Both options are legit and each option has own scenarios where it is more effective then another.

Of course always use await when you want to handle result of the asynchronous method or handle possible exception in current method

```
public async Task Execute()
{
    try
    {
        await RunAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle thrown exception
    }
}
```

If you don't use result of asynchronous method in current method - return the Task. This approach will delay state machine creation to the caller or where ever final task will be awaited. As pointed in the comments can make execution little bit more effective.

But there are scenarios where you must await for the task, even you do nothing with result and don't want handle possible exceptions

```
public Task<Entity> GetEntity(int id)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
    {
        return context.Entities.FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

In the scenario above, `FindAsync` can return not completed task and this task will be returned straight away to the caller and dispose `context` object created within `using` statement.
Later when caller will "await" for the task exception will be thrown because it will try to use already disposed object(`context`).

```
public async Task<Entity> GetEntity(int id)
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
    {
        return await context.Entities.FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

And traditionally answers about Async Await **must** include link to Stephen Cleary's blog
[Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Answer (score 1):

Await is a sequencing feature which allows the caller to receive the result of an async method and do something with it. If you do not need to process the result of an async function, you do not have to await it.

In your example `Func1()` and `Func2()` do no process the return values of the called async functions, so it is fine not to await them.

Answer (score 1):

When you use await the code will wait for the async function to finish. This should be done when you need a value from an async function, like this case:

```
int salary = await CalculateSalary();

...

async Task<int> CalculateSalary()
{
    //Start high cpu usage task
    ...
    //End high cpu usage task
    return salary;
}
```

If you hadn't use the the await this would happen:

```
int salary = CalculateSalary().Result;

...

async Task<int> CalculateSalary()
{
    //Start high cpu usage task
    ... //In some line of code the function finishes returning null because we didn't wait the function to finish
    return salary; //This never runs
}
```

Await means, wait this async function to finish.

Use it to your needs, your case 1 and 2 would produce the same result, as long as you await when you assign the info value the code will be safe.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 2nd one will do because await is expecting a return value.
Since it is waiting for the `Func1()` to return a value, `Func1()` is already executing `Func2()` which is returning a value.